# Magento 2 memory size needed for process

Tags: magento2.2, memory, memory-leak

I am using `Magento 2.2`. I need to know the suitable **RAM Size** needed to run my Magento system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get reference from here :

- [Magento System Requirements](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/magento/magento-system-requirements.html)
- [Magento Official Docs](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html)